# What is the difference between the apply() function and a function call using the object of the class?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, apply

Consider Atom to be a class where

- form.name is a string
- convert returns a list of values

**What is the difference between the following two lines?**

- `apply(Atom, [form.name] + list([convert(arg, subst) for arg in
     list(form.args)]))`
- `Atom(form.name, [convert(arg, subst) for arg in form.args])`

From documentation,

> apply(...)
>       apply(object[, args[, kwargs]]) -> value
>       Call a callable object with positional arguments taken from the tuple args,
>       and keyword arguments taken from the optional dictionary kwargs.
>       Note that classes are callable, as are instances with a **call**() method.

I am not able to understand the difference between the two lines. I am trying to find an equivalent code for `apply(Atom, [form.name] + list([convert(arg, subst) for arg in list(form.args)]))` in Python 3.5

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`apply` is an old-school<sup>1</sup> way of [unpacking arguments](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/controlflow.html#tut-unpacking-arguments).  In other words, the following all yield the same results:

```
results = apply(foo, [1, 2, 3])
results = foo(*[1, 2, 3])
results = foo(1, 2, 3)
```

Since you're working in python3.5 where `apply` no longer exists, the option is not valid.  Additionally, you're working with the arguments as a list so you can't really use the third option either.  The only option left is the second one.  We can pretty easily transform your expression into that format. The equivalent in python3.5 would be:

```
Atom(*([form.name] + [convert(arg, subst) for arg in list(form.args)]))
```

<sup><sup>1</sup>It was deprecated in python2.3!</sup>

Comment: It works.. but can you tell me which concept is used here so that I can read about it. What is Atom(*...)? What does the * represent?

Comment: Got it! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-and-star-do-for-parameters

Comment: @Dennis -- That's how we now unpack arguments in modern python.  I've added a link above where you can read more about it in the python tutorial

Comment: @Dennis -- Also, be a little careful with that link you posted.  Specifically, that link specifies what it means to have a `*` at the function definition point.  This question is more about what it means to have a `*` at the function _call_ point.  They're closely related concepts (closely related enough that it's easy to overlook the fact that they're different when you've been working with it for a while), but they are distinct things that can be understood separately.